# Rails 4 - How to route delete path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have been using Rails 3 and am trying to use Rails 4.  I am following a ToDo tutorial here: http://www.codelearn.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial/introduction-views-layouts-helpers-assets-pipeline

I am trying to delete the ToDo item using the Rails 'link_to' helper method, and have been looking up online and have not been able to get it to work for the past 90 minutes so I decided to ask for help.

Here is the error message I am getting:

```
Routing Error
No route matches [DELETE] "/todos/delete_path"
```

Here is my 'rake routes' from the terminal:

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern             Controller#Action
 todos_index GET    /todos/index(.:format)  todos#index
todos_delete DELETE /todos/delete(.:format) todos#delete
```

Here is the 'link_to' helper method from inside of the:

```
index.html.erb

<%= link_to 'Delete last todo', 'delete_path', method: :delete %>
```

Here is my:

```
routes.rb

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'todos/index'
  # get 'todos/delete'
  match 'todos/delete' => 'todos#delete', via: :delete
```

Here is my:

```
todos_controller.rb

class TodosController < ApplicationController
  def index
    # @todo_array = ['Buy Milk', 'Buy Soap', 'Pay bill', 'Draw Money']
    @todo_items = Todo.all
    render :index
  end

  def delete
    #put delete logic here
    @todo_items = Todo.last
    @todo_items.destroy
  end

end
```

Thank you for taking the time to look at my problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you would write a destroy method:

```
def destroy
  @todo = Todo.last
  @todo.destroy
  redirect_to todos_index_path #or wherever you want to redirect user after deleting the tod
end
```

Also, I would simply use RESTful routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :todos, only: %i(index destroy)
end
```